# cannot find module 'readable-stream/transform'

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to use to npm to install anything, and nothing works. I get the error code 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' and 'cannot find module 'readable-stream/transform''.

I've tried uninstall and reinstalling nodejs. In the process I lost nodemon and now I can't even reinstall it because of this error.
This is the log of the error from Appdata/Roaming/npm-cache/_logs

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'i' ]
2 info using npm@6.9.0
3 info using node@v10.16.0
4 verbose stack Error: Cannot find module 'readable-stream/transform'
4 verbose stack     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
4 verbose stack     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
4 verbose stack     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:690:17)
4 verbose stack     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
4 verbose stack     at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\mississippi\node_modules\through2\through2.js:1:17)
4 verbose stack     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
4 verbose stack     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
4 verbose stack     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
4 verbose stack     at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
4 verbose stack     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
4 verbose stack     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:690:17)
4 verbose stack     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
4 verbose stack     at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\mississippi\index.js:5:26)
4 verbose stack     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
4 verbose stack     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
4 verbose stack     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
5 verbose cwd C:\Users\adamn\Desktop\Development\adamNode
6 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17134
7 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "i"
8 verbose node v10.16.0
9 verbose npm  v6.9.0
10 error code MODULE_NOT_FOUND
11 error Cannot find module 'readable-stream/transform'
12 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

npm install should install different modules but I just get errors instead.

Comment: How can we reproduce this?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your question

Comment: For us to help you, we need a bit more of background. Your package.json and such. We need to write "npm install" and see the problem, just like you do in your environment. You have to create a minimal example to reproduce the problem, as you can read here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and also, maybe, preparing the example you find a solution, which is good for your and for us. EDIT: I did not downvote actually, but is not a good question to receive answers easily. You have to improve it. PD: Welcome to StackOverflow hehe.

Comment: @JorgeFuentesGonzález, May you can help us!
Just tell us where the npm looking for this module!?
At least I`d just trying a sample from Angular JS, git cloned it and in the folder of sample hit the "npm install"

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but it solved by taking long hours of googling.
The problem is a package named **mississippi** is outdated and cause the problem!

From you error log:

```
4 verbose stack     at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\mississippi\node_modules\through2\through2.js:1:17)
```

Where you can some useful things about it: [github#1809](https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/1809)

Just remove the 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules' folder, unInstall the nodejs and npm and reinstall them again!

Additional information for **Arch Linux** users, that modules are not located under '/opt/local/lib/node_modules' as other distributions or installation mechanism, And so remove and installation of the nodejs and npm will not solve the problem!

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/lib/node_modules
sudo pacman -S nodejs npm
```